# Eigenvalues and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If A is a symmetric matrix whose eigenvalues have absolute values that are less than $1$, then:
$$\det(I-A)\neq0$$
where $I$ is identity matrix.

Why is that inequality correct?

Comment: This is false, for $A=I$.

Comment: It is not correct as written. Choose $A=I$. This matrix is clearly symmetric, has some eigenvalues (equal to $1$), but $det(I-A)=0$.

Comment: ok, I edited question

Comment: This holds when $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Sorry I forget to add this.

Comment: This is a simple consequence of the definition of eigenvalues: $\lambda I-A$ is singular iff $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see "symmetric" (even normal is enough), diagonalize!
\begin{align}
\det(I - A) &=  \det(UIU^* - U\Lambda U^*) \\&= \det(U(I-\Lambda) U^*) 
\\&=  \det(U)\det(I-\Lambda)\det(U^*) 
\\&= \det(I-\Lambda) \\&= \prod\limits_{j=1}^n (1-\lambda_j) 
\\\det(I - A) &= 0 \iff \exists j\colon\lambda_j = 1
\end{align}

Comment: Now I feel bad for not including that the last line is naturally true for any $A$, but I don't want to bump this post.

Answer (score 1):

Mosquito-nuking solution:
$$\rho(A) < 1\implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A^n\text{ is convergent}$$
(see [Neumann series and spectral radius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242425/neumann-series-and-spectral-radius)) and
$$(I - A)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A^n\text{ exists}.$$