# Infinite series of matrix powers to compute inverse

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, inverse

Show how to use an infinite series of matrix powers to compute $A^{-1}$ for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Which conditions must be satisfied by the eigenvalues of $A$ for the series to converge?

Comment: A hint to get you started: for $x\in (-1,1)$ we have $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$.

Comment: I already found [this explatation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/992330/152622). So I need to find a $B$ so that $A=(I-B)$, $\|B\|<1$ and then the cauchy sequence converges to $A^{-1}$. I am just not sure how to formaly proof this.

Comment: @Math1000 I think you meant the reverse inequality.

Comment: Indeed, $\|A\|\geqslant |\lambda|$ for any eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: @Math1000 where does this come from? This seems to contradict the information [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/242443/152622)

Comment: If $\|x\|=1$ and $Ax=\lambda x$, then $\|Ax\| = \|\lambda x\| = |\lambda|$...